# Guía para montar aplicación web de principiante, con base de datos en access

Tags: web, aplicación-web, ms-access

Buen día, me han enseñado en la universidad como crear una app web utilizando Neetbeans con ficheros .jsp

He creado una base de datos en access, y he logrado hacer la conexión de mi aplicación web a la BD de access, a tal grado que si corro en neetbeans mi aplicación funciona a la perfección.

click en un botón, me conecta a la base de datos y jalá los datos que le pedi, etc. etc.

El asunto esta en que quiero montar esa aplicación en appserv, o en otro similiar.

Cuando copio los archivos construidos por el compilador del neetbeans y los pego en la carpeta wwww de appserv entonces la aplicación ya no me funciona, al parecer no me lee el codigo java ni funciona la Base de datos en access.

Comment: Si estás intentando que tu aplicación funcione en un servidor web Apache no te va a funcionar. Tienes que desplegar tu aplicación en un contenedor web como Apache Tomcat, o en un servidor de aplicaciones como JBoss, Glassfish, IBM WAS...

Comment: Hola, tengo apache tomcat, he configurado las variable de entorno CATALINA_HOME

Pero no puedo solucionar el problema que me dice:
Que catalina no es un comando reconocido....

Comment: Mil gracias, lo he solucionado, configure la variable catalina_home del tomcat e inicio el servicio desde el cmd, copio el war a webapp del tomcat y listo el descomprime solo y lee todo a la perfección.